# Java if statement data entry restriction

Tags: java, string, indexof

I'm trying to get the hang of how `.indexOf()` works after reading about it. I've created a random string and trying to search for the character `a`.

However, after trying a few things I get this error, though I've always stated `String` at all stages:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

A million thanks to all those who can help me understand where I'm going wrong or suggest the right way to do it.

```
public class sad
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String stringwords;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class sad
     */
    public void sad()
    {
        stringwords = "this is some words a cat";
    }

    //
    public void search()
    {
      String a = stringwords.indexOf("a");
           System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns an `int` not a `String` do `int a = stringwords.indexOf("a");` Also the constructor should be `public sad()` without the void.

Comment: Please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`). Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`), and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)         indexof method in String return int

Comment: Awesome that makes more sense. good job guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `stringwords.indexOf("a");` is an integer. You are simply asking in what position does the letter `a` occur, which gives its position in numbers.

For example:

```
String test = "Hello";
int a = test.indexOf("e");
//a = 1. First letter has the value 0, the next one 1 and so forth.
```

Do this:

```
public class sad
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String stringwords;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class sad
     */
    public sad()
    {
        stringwords = "this is some words a cat";
    }

    //
    public void search()
    {
      int a = stringwords.indexOf("a");
           System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: change that `constructor` :P

Comment: @3kings I edited it, but it works either way. Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 4):

[`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) returns the index of the given string within the string it's called on. You cannot assign this return value to a `String` - it must be assigned to an `int`:

```
int index = stringwords.indexOf("a");
```

Answer (score 3):

indexOf returns a String. Look at the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

```
public class sad
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String stringwords;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class sad
     */
    public sad()
    {
        stringwords = "this is some words a cat";
    }

    //
    public void search()
    {
      int a = stringwords.indexOf("a");
           System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: change that `constructor` :P